# Hashmap (O(1)) supporting joker/match-all keys

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hashmap, lookup

The title is not so clear, because I cannot put my problem in a sentence (If you have a better title for this question, please suggest). I'll try to clarify my requirement with an example:

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
| Origin | Destination | Airline   | Free Baggage |
===================================================
| NYC    | London      | American  | 20KG         |
---------------------------------------------------
| NYC    | *           | Southwest | 30KG         |
---------------------------------------------------
| *      | *           | Southwest | 25KG         |
---------------------------------------------------
| *      | LA          | *         | 20KG         |
---------------------------------------------------
| *      | *           | *         | 15KG         |
---------------------------------------------------
and so on ...
```

This table describes free baggage amount that the airlines provide in different routes. You can see that some rows have `*` value, meaning that they match all possible values (those values are not known necessarily).

So we have a large list of **baggage rules** (like the table above) and a large list of **flights** (which their origin, destination and airline is known), and we intend to find the baggage amount for each one of flights in the most efficient way (iterating the list is not an efficient way, obviously, as it will cost an `O(N)` computation). It **is** possible to exist more than one result for each flight, but we will assume that in this case either the first matching or the most specific one will be preferred (whichever is simpler for you to continue with).

If there was not `*` signs in the table, the problem would be easy, and we could use a `Hashmap` or `Dictionary` with a `Tuple` of values as a key. But with presence of those `*` (lets say match-all) keys, it is not so straight forward to provide a general solution for that.

Please note that the above example was just an example, and I need a solution that can be used for any number of keys, not just three.

Do you have any idea or implementation for this problem, with a lookup method having time complexity equal or close to `O(1)` like a regular hashmap (memory will not be an issue)? What would be the best possible solution?

Comment: Question: do you need _only_ these `*` special entries/jokers, or can you find things like `*America*`, or `NY?`, and other "usual" joker expressions?

Comment: @Wisblade No, in my example just a single `*` indicates that all values are matched. Something like `*America*` is not considered.

Comment: OK. So, if I search for "NYC" in your example, I should get the whole 5 rows, and if I search for "ZZZ", I'll get the 3 bottom lines. On the other side, if I search for "*", I'll get all rows. That's correct?

Comment: What is the free baggage amount if you match multiple rules with different free baggage?  Is it first rule wins, or highest free amount wins?

Comment: @Wisblade You would not search `NYC`, but you would search `(NYC, LA, American)`, and you will get one result.

Comment: @btilly As I mentioned in the question, in case that more than one rows are matched, we will get either the first match or the most specific one (whichever you find easier).

Comment: OK. And you _never_ search for `(NYC, *, American)`, for example, or it's a real use case to be allowed to do so?

Comment: @Wisblade The comment above is also for you.

Comment: @Wisblade Exactly.

Comment: @Ahmad It would be nice to get a feedback on your problem: you got three answers, none is neither upvoted nor selected as answer...

Comment: Oh, of course @Wisblade, I'm just trying to analyze it completely and give you that feedback, that is taking a little long.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the comments, the more I think about it, and the more it looks like a relational database with indexes rather than an hashmap...

A trivial, quite easy solution could be something like an [In-memory SQlite database](https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html). But it would probably be something in `O(log2(n))`, and not `O(1)`. The main advantage is that it's easy to set up, and **IF** performances are good enough, it could be the final solution.
Here, key is to use proper indexes, the `LIKE` operator, and of course well-defined `JOIN` clauses.

---

From scratch, I can't think about any solution that, having `N` rows and `M` columns, isn't at least in `O(M)`... But usually, you'll have way less columns than rows. Quickly - I may have skipped a detail, I write that on-the-fly - I can propose you this algorithm / container:

1. Data must be stored in a vector-like container `VECDATA`, accessed by a simple index in `O(1)`. Think about this as a *primary key* in databases, and we'll call it `PK`. Knowing `PK` gives you instantly, in `O(1)`, the required data. You'll have `N` rows grand total.
2. For each row NOT containing any `*`, you'll insert in a real hashmap called `MAINHASH` the pair `(<tuple>, PK)`. This is your primary index, for exact results. It will be in `O(1)`, **BUT** what you requested may not be within... Obviously, you must maintain consistency between `MAINHASH` and `VECDATA`, with whatever is needed (mutexes, locks, don't care as long as both are consistents).
   This hash contains at most `N` entries. Without any joker, it will act near as a standard hashmap, but for the indirection to `VECDATA`. It's still `O(1)` in this case.
3. For each searchable column, you'll build a specific index, dedicated to this column.
   The index has `N` entries. It will be a standard hashmap, but it **MUST** allow multiple values for a given key. That's quite a common container, so it shouldn't be an issue.
   For each row, the index entry will be: `( <VECDATA value>, PK )`. The container is stored in a vector of indexes, `INDEX[i]` (with `0<=i<M`).
   Same as `MAINHASH`, consistency must be enforced.

Obviously, all these indexes / subcontainers should be constructed when an entry is inserted into `VECDATA`, and saved on disk across sessions if needed - you don't want to reconstruct all this each time you start the application...

---

### Searching a row

So, user search for a given tuple.

1. Search it in `MAINHASH`. If found, return it, search done.
   Upgrade (see below): search also in `CACHE` before going to step #2.
2. For each tuple element `tuple[0<=i<M]`, search in `INDEX[i]` for both `tuple[i]` (returns a vector of `PK`, `EXACT[i]`) **AND** for `*` (returns another vector of `PK`, `FUZZY[i]`).
3. With these two vectors, build another (temporary) hash `TMPHASH`, associating `( PK, integer COUNT )`. It quite simple: `COUNT` is initialized to `1` if entry comes from `EXACT`, and `0` if it comes from `FUZZY`.
4. For next column, build `EXACT` and `FUZZY` (see #2). But instead of making a new `TMPHASH`, you'll ***MERGE*** the results into rather than creating a new temporary hash.
   Method is: if `TMPHASH` doesn't have this `PK` entry, trash this entry: it can't match at all. Otherwise, read the `COUNT` value, add `1` or `0` to it according to where it comes from, reinject it in `TMPHASH`.
5. Once all columns are done, you'll have to analyze `TMPHASH`.

### Analyzing `TMPHASH`

First, if `TMPHASH` is empty, then you don't have any suitable answer. Return that to user. If it contains only one entry, same: return to user directly.
For more than one element in `TMPHASH`:

- Parse the whole `TMPHASH` container, searching for the maximum `COUNT`. Maintain in memory the `PK` associated to the current maximum for `COUNT`.
- Developper's choice: in case of multiple `COUNT` at the same maximum value, you can either return them all, return the first one, or the last one.
- `COUNT` if obviously always stricly lower than `M` - otherwise, you would have found the tuple in `MAINHASH`. This value, compared to `M`, can give a confidence mark to your result (=`100*COUNT/M`% of confidence).
- You can also now store the original tuple searched, and the corresponding `PK`, in another hashmap called `CACHE`.
  Since it would be way too complicated to update properly `CACHE` when adding/modifying something in `VECDATA`, simply purge `CACHE` when it occurs. It's only a cache, after all...

---

This is quite complex to implement if the language doesn't help you, in particular by allowing to redefine operators and having all base containers available, but it should work.

Exact matches / cached matches are in `O(1)`. Fuzzy search is in `O(n.M)`, `n` being the number of matching rows (and `0<=n<N`, of course).

Without further researchs, I can't see anything better than that. It will consume an obscene amount of memory, but you said that it won't be an issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for you nice try to solve the problem. Just there is one thing that you may can explain to me: I'm a little worried that constructing and analyzing `TMPHASH` becomes the bottleneck of the algorithm. As you may have a lot of entries with keys having same value at index `i`, you will have to iterate the whole list of them, that may affect the performance. Please confirm that I'm right, and I will try to find a way to make it better.

Comment: @Ahmad Indeed, there is _**always**_ a bottleneck in _**every**_ complex algorithm - it cannot be avoided. The first step (finding the entry with the biggest `COUNT` value) isn't so much of a bottleneck: TMPHASH won't contain more data than its size on _FIRST_ iteration of "Searching a row". It won't be so big. You can try a `sort` on it on `COUNT`, IF you plan to return ALL matches. If you want only one (first found), don't bother to sort, brute force parsing will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing this with [Trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)s that have a little data decorated.  For routes, you want to know the lowest route ID so we can match to the first available route.  For flights you want to track how many flights there are left to match.

What this will allow you to do, for instance, is partway through the match ONLY ONCE realize that flights from city1 to city2 might be matching routes that start off `city1, city2`, or `city1, *` or `*, city2`, or `*, *` without having to repeat that logic for each route or flight.

Here is a proof of concept in Python:

```
import heapq
import weakref

class Flight:
    def __init__(self, fields, flight_no):
        self.fields = fields
        self.flight_no = flight_no

class Route:
    def __init__(self, route_id, fields, baggage):
        self.route_id = route_id
        self.fields = fields
        self.baggage = baggage

class SearchTrie:
    def __init__(self, value=0, item=None, parent=None):
        # value = # unmatched flights for flights
        # value = lowest route id for routes.
        self.value = value
        self.item = item
        self.trie = {}
        self.parent = None
        if parent:
            self.parent = weakref.ref(parent)

    def add_flight (self, flight, i=0):
        self.value += 1
        fields = flight.fields
        if i < len(fields):
            if fields[i] not in self.trie:
                self.trie[fields[i]] = SearchTrie(0, None, self)
            self.trie[fields[i]].add_flight(flight, i+1)
        else:
            self.item = flight

    def remove_flight(self):
        self.value -= 1
        if self.parent and self.parent():
            self.parent().remove_flight()

    def add_route (self, route, i=0):
        route_id = route.route_id
        fields = route.fields
        if i < len(fields):
            if fields[i] not in self.trie:
                self.trie[fields[i]] = SearchTrie(route_id)
            self.trie[fields[i]].add_route(route, i+1)
        else:
            self.item = route

    def match_flight_baggage(route_search, flight_search):
        # Construct a heap of one search to do.
        tmp_id = 0
        todo = [((0, tmp_id), route_search, flight_search)]
        # This will hold by flight number, baggage.
        matched = {}

        while 0 < len(todo):
            priority, route_search, flight_search = heapq.heappop(todo)
            if 0 == flight_search.value: # There are no flights left to match
                # Already matched all flights.
                pass
            elif flight_search.item is not None:
                # We found a match!
                matched[flight_search.item.flight_no] = route_search.item.baggage
                flight_search.remove_flight()
            else:
                for key, r_search in route_search.trie.items():
                    if key == '*': # Found wildcard.
                        for a_search in flight_search.trie.values():
                            if 0 < a_search.value:
                                heapq.heappush(todo, ((r_search.value, tmp_id), r_search, a_search))
                                tmp_id += 1
                    elif key in flight_search.trie and 0 < flight_search.trie[key].value:
                        heapq.heappush(todo, ((r_search.value, tmp_id), r_search, flight_search.trie[key]))
                        tmp_id += 1

        return matched

# Sample data - the id is the position.
route_data = [
    ["NYC", "London", "American", "20KG"],
    ["NYC", "*", "Southwest", "30KG"],
    ["*", "*", "Southwest", "25KG"],
    ["*", "LA", "*", "20KG"],
    ["*", "*", "*", "15KG"],
]
routes = []
for i in range(len(route_data)):
    data = route_data[i]
    routes.append(Route(i, [data[0], data[1], data[2]], data[3]))

flight_data = [
    ["NYC", "London", "American"],
    ["NYC", "Dallas", "Southwest"],
    ["Dallas", "Houston", "Southwest"],
    ["Denver", "LA", "American"],
    ["Denver", "Houston", "American"],
]
flights = []
for i in range(len(flight_data)):
    data = flight_data[i]
    flights.append(Flight([data[0], data[1], data[2]], i))

# Convert to searches.
flight_search = SearchTrie()
for flight in flights:
    flight_search.add_flight(flight)

route_search = SearchTrie()
for route in routes:
    route_search.add_route(route)


print(route_search.match_flight_baggage(flight_search))
```

Answer (score 0):

As Wisblade notices in his answer, for an array of `N` rows and `M` columns the best possible complexity is `O(M)`. You can get `O(1)` only if you consider `M` to be a constant.

You can easily solve your problem in `O(2^M)` which is practical for a small `M` and is effectively `O(1)` if you consider `M` to be a constant.

Create a single hashmap which contains (as keys) strings of concatenated column values, possibly separated by some special character, e.g. a slash:

```
map.put("NYC/London/American", "20KG");
map.put("NYC/*/Southwest", "30KG");
map.put("*/*/Southwest", "25KG");
map.put("*/LA/*", "20KG");
map.put("*/*/*", "15KG");
```

Then, when you query, you try different combinations of actual data and wildcard characters. E.g. let's assume you want to query `NYC/LA/Southwest`; then you try the following combinations:

```
map.get("NYC/LA/Southwest"); // null
map.get("NYC/LA/*"); // null
map.get("NYC/*/Southwest"); // found: 30KG
```

If the answer in the third step was null, you would continue as follows:

```
map.get("NYC/*/*"); // null
map.get("*/LA/Southwest"); // null
map.get("*/LA/*"); // found: 20KG
```

And there still remain two options:

```
map.get("*/*/Southwest"); // found: 25KG
map.get("*/*/*"); // found: 15KG
```

Basically, for three data columns you have 8 possibilities to check in the hashmap -- not bad! and possibly you find an answer much earlier.